# How does iOS detect the internet connection?

Tags: ios, network-programming

I'm making a little WiFi controllable DMX widget for my personal use and I was wondering how to let devices (Particularly the iPhone) know that there is no internet on the network. Currently, the phone will try to use the data from the WiFi network and since there is no internet, the page fails to load.

If you've ever used the gopro 5, the phone knows right away that there is no internet. Here's an example of what I'm talking about (8:49): https://youtu.be/hMdVJPQDsmc?t=8m49s How would I implement this on my own network?

Comment: Try [Reachability](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift) for this task.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you clarify?